# Dao, Service layer in legacy code

Tags: java, spring, ejb, cdi

This Question is about design in business layer. What is the best way to instantiate Dao or Service class in legacy code.
new in every class where Dao or Service is needed is imho bad approach.
They should be stateless, singletons. For sure I am not able to use Spring, CDI, EJB or another DI frameworks.
My ideas was something like this:

- **Factory method (Singleton)**
- **Enum Singletone**
- **Static methods** (IMHO bad approach)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's stateless, making it a singleton or creating a new instance every time you want an instance won't make any significant difference. Using any of those 3 approaches makes it even harder to unit test your code.

If DI is completely out of the question, you could use the poor man's dependency injection to at least make your code testable:

```
public class SomeService {

    private SomeDao someDao;

    /**
     * Constructor used in production. Creates or looks up its own DAO
     */
    public SomeService() {
        this.someDao = new SomeDao();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor used by unit tests, which can pass a mock DAO instance.
     */
    public SomeService(SomeDao someDao) {
        this.someDao = someDao;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: If I create object via new, Java will always create new object(memory consumption) Imagine that you use one of service class in 4 another class so you got 4 service instance + 4 dao instance instead of just 1 + 1. Should I even take care about it?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. That's a tiny piece of memory: 128 bytes vs. 32 bytes.